# Next.js fonts served from public folder have wrong content-type

Tags: next.js, font-face, content-type

I've got a Next.js site where I'm serving some self-hosted fonts using @font-face and locally the fonts come through fine with no errors and the correct content-type, like so:

[image]

But once I get it up on a production server, the fonts are being served, but getting 500 errors and coming through with the content-type text/html.

[image]

Not sure what is going on here. I've served fonts through the public folder before on other sites without a problem. This is on Digital Ocean with a custom express server handling a few extra things. I've tried different font file types, moving the font directory, etc.

What's even stranger is that I only get the 500 errors on Chrome. Both Safari and Firefox will serve the fonts with status 200, but their content-type is still txt.

Here is the [staging server](http://159.65.105.127/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a CORS issue. I had to update my CORS policy through Express.js to allow the remote server. This resolved the issue for me.

[image]